# ANCOVA (GLM) versus Mixed Linear Model with covariate measured at both pre- and post-treatment (in SPSS)

Tags: spss, covariance, ancova, mixed-model

I'm trying to analyze a pre/post study with 4 treatment groups.  The Dependent Variable, **Speed**, measures how quickly a person's facial expression reaches peak intensity; this measure is normally distributed after log10 transformation.  Another variable, **Intensity** of emotional expression, is also measured at both pre and post and might influence the **Speed**.  **Intensity** is continuous and not normally distributed.

**Question:**  If Intensity does indeed significantly correlate with Speed, how should this be accounted for, statistically?  IF Intensity was "fixed"/static, I would think that (using SPSS), I would choose the repeated-measures option of the General Linear Model, and enter Intensity a covariate.  However, since Intensity is measured--and not identical--at both pre- and post-, can Intensity be included as a covariate?  If so, how (Enter 2 covariates: Intensity at pre, and Intensity at post?; Create a change-score to use as the covariate?).  In one of the treatment conditions, Intensity is significantly different at post-treatment.

**Update:**  I've been advised that mixed-effects modelling (mixed linear model) might be the way to go.  After a quick look, the mixed approach seems appropriate, but please advise if you think that there are better/easier options.

My stats and SPSS skills are fairly basic so, if explanations can be calibrated to novice-level, it'd be much appreciated.